# Pagination are not working with filtering Django

Tags: django, pagination, filtering, django-filter

I had a `Listview` that worked perfectly with pagination it looked like:

```
class BranchListView(ListView):
    model = Branch
    paginate_by = 10
```

Now I need to change it to `Filterview` and used `django_filters`, I'm trying to create pagination in a `FilterView` this way

```
class BranchListView(FilterView):
    model = Branch
    paginate_by = 10
    filter_class = BranchFilter
    template_name = 'erp_system/branch_list.html'
    filterset_fields = ['id', 'name']
```

And this how I use pagination part in the template

```
{% if is_paginated %}
    <div class="pagination">
        <span class="page-links">
            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}"><button
                        class="btn-success">الصفحة السابقة</button> </a>
            {% endif %}
            <span class="page-current">
                 صفحة رقم  {{ page_obj.number }} من {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
            </span>
            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}"><button class="btn-success">الصفحة التالية</button> </a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Now the filtering is working perfectly. But there is no pagination at all.